# I wonder if evince document viewer have configuration file like zathura have zathurarc?

Tags: shortcut-keys, pdf, evince, document, zathura

I use zathura as document viewer but they not provide highlight text option , or I not found any plugin for that.

So I switched to evince but how I configure keybindings in evince actually I saw this question related to keybindings but they not provide from way any file.

Like zathura have file called zathurarc in ~/.config/zathura/zathurarc to set keybindings , I like more vim like keybindings

**my question is how to configure evince , is their is any file like evincerc like zathura or there other way to configure it?**